# Windows OS manager changed boot settings after UEFI firmware update

Tags: boot, debian, windows-11, grub, uefi

I've dual booted my HP laptop with Debian and Windows 11, and GRUB boot menu was shown on boot as usual.

Recently, my HP laptop got a UEFI firmware update; due to which, now Windows boots directly from itself, without GRUB, and I was not able to boot into Debian. I searched a bit, changed the boot order once I booted into Linux using UEFI boot menu settings, and it worked fine if I only use Debian, but as soon as I boot into Windows again, I found that it has restored the boot settings.

- I found this [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1311154/1878714), but it seems a little dangerous

I would like to know why this is happening and are there any workarounds for it?

Comment: On HP machines, I find that they try to go directly to the MS boot, as you state. On those PC's,  renaming the boot files worked well for me. See https://superuser.com/questions/1332149/cant-get-grub-to-handle-booting-windows-boot-manager-keeps-taking-control and also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481059/i-renamed-grubx64-efi-file-to-bootmgfw-efi-to-dual-boot-is-it-right , though.

Comment: @StudentDev: Where did you get this BIOS update and why was it necessary to do that? What model is your motherboard? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I got the BIOS update from the Windows update system only. At first I thought it is just usual windows updates(that did not change boot settings), but it updated the BIOS.
Motherboard info:

Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: 88EA
        Version: 81.51

Comment: The HP site cannot find it by motherboard name. What is the computer model?

Comment: @harrymc HP Laptop: 15s-fq3066TU

Comment: @StudentDev AFAIK, Windows Update can't provide UEFI firmware updates because it requires a standalone program from the motherboard manufacturer and Windows Update doesn't download `.exe` programs AFAIK _(it will provide driver updates from different OEMs)_

Answer (score 0):

It's uncommon for Windows Update to suggest a BIOS update
(never happened to me).

The latest BIOS version for your computer according to the HP site is
[F.21 Rev.A](https://support.hp.com/hr-en/drivers/hp-15.6-inch-laptop-pc-15-d3000/model/2100386441?sku=7W475PA).
As this version dates from September 16, 2021, it's
very puzzling why you suddenly needed to update the BIOS in 2023.

I suggest to install the BIOS from the HP website
(after verifying again that it pertains to your computer model),
and then refuse any future BIOS update suggestions from Windows Update.

Comment: I have checked the BIOS version using `dmidecode`, it is F.63 though the release date is 10/05/2023.